# Summing order totals Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to Mysql and need help trying to combine two mysql queries that give a "total" for each "storeid" from the orders total. I'm currently using two queries to get the result:

```
SELECT storeid, storenum, name  FROM store ORDER BY storeid DESC

SELECT SUM((1+0.07125)*qty*discprice) as total FROM items WHERE orderid IN (SELECT orderid      FROM orders WHERE store = '".$row['storeid']."' AND date >= '2012-01-01' AND date < '2013-01-01')
```

I'm running a while loop and running the second query with the "storeid". However, I know I can do this is one query and group by "storeid" and create a total for all stores combined. But I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Sub Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.storeid, s.storenum, s.name
       SUM((1+0.07125)*i.qty*i.discprice) AS total
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN orders AS o 
    ON i.orderid=o.orderid
LEFT JOIN stores AS s 
    ON o.store=s.storeid
WHERE o.date >= '2012-01-01'
  AND o.date < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY s.storeid, s.storenum, s.name;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will have to look at the Sub Queries link and study this query to understand exactly how it works, but I'm starting to understand the concept.

Comment: @XanderNGCC It doesn't use subqueries, your original query used them but this one just uses and outer join.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to join the three tables and then use an aggregate function on the `items` table.

```
SELECT stores.storeid, stores.storenum, stores.name, SUM((1+0.07125)*items.qty*items.discprice) as total 
FROM stores
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.storeid=stores.storeid AND orders.date>='2012-01-01' AND orders.date<'2013-01-01' 
LEFT JOIN items  ON items.orderid=orders.orderid
GROUP BY stores.storeid, stores.storenum, stores.name
```

What this does it this:

It will select every store from the `stores` table, and sum up the orders in that store. I chose a LEFT JOIN instead of straight JOINs, so that stores without any order in that time span will still show up with a total of NULL.

P.S. I don't have a copy of your database's schema, above SQL query might not actually work as expected - it is just supposed to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't propagate bad habits. You should only select columns that you group by or aggregates. That query won't work in any other db than MySQL. In this case it won't produce wrong results but in other such habit will.

Comment: You are right in that standard SQL will require the extra columns in the GROUP BY clause. It should only be used when the possible implications of this notations are understood, and as such is a bad example for somebody just getting into (My)SQL. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is your answer edited now? I'm just looking at it for the first time so I don't have anything to compare it to. I'm assuming you only included one of the columns under the GROUP BY clause originally, not all three?

Comment: Yes, it now shows three GROUP BY columns. The original had only one, which gives identical results in MySQL but may be misleading for novice SQL users.